# Insert picture not pasting in active cell

Tags: excel-2007

```
Sub InsertLogo1()
    ActiveCell.Select
    ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert("Path").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Above code does not insert Picture in activecell, in just inserts it on the top left Hand Corner or the active sheet. This Problem happens to me only on Excel 2007. Please advise

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim Pic As Object
Set Pic = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(Directory & "\" & filename)
With Pic
    .Top = ActiveCell.Top
    .Left = ActiveCell.Left
    .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
    .Width = 225#
End With
```

Comment: It is working on my machine but still Need to test it on another one. Will confirm tomorrow.thank you for the prompt Initial answer

Comment: Your always welcome...I am also new to stack overflow and i love helping people:)...Have a great day!!!